# Are the same IDs always given out across the same logic plan?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Beneath you see a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I load a `Dataframe` from 150 `parquets`(>10TB) stored in S3, Then I give this dataframe an id column with `func.monotonically_increasing_id()`. Afterwards I save a couple of deviates of this `dataframe`. The function I apply are a little bit more complicated than I present here but I hope this gets the point across

```
DF_loaded = spark.read.parquet(/some/path/*/')
DF_with_IDs = DF_loaded.withColumn('id',func.monotonically_increasing_id())
#creating parquet_1    
DF_with_IDs.where(col('a').isNotNull()).write.parquet('/path/parquet_1/')
#creating parquet_2
DF_with_IDs.where(col('b').isNotNull()).write.parquet('/path/parquet_2/')
```

now I noticed that spark after creating `parquet_1` loads again all the data from S3 to create `parquet_2`. Now I'm worried that the IDs given to `parquet_1` do not match those of `parquet_2`. That the same row has different IDs in both `parquets`. Because as far is I understand it the logic plan spark comes up with looks like this:

```
#parquet_1
load_data -> give_ids -> make_selection -> write_parquet
#parquet_2
load_data -> give_ids -> make_selection -> write_parquet
```

So are the same IDs given to the same rows in both `parquets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as:

- You use a recent version of Spark ([SPARK-13473](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13473), [SPARK-14241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14241)).
- There is no configuration change between actions (Changes in a configuration can affect number of partitions and as a result ids).

`monotonically_increasing_id` should be stable. Note that this disables predicate pushdown.

`rdd.zipWithindex.toDF` should be stable independent of configuration, so it might be preferable.